# When importing Contributions, every record returns an error: No matching Contact found for ( ##### )

Tags: contributions, import

When importing Contributions, every record returns an error: No matching Contact found for ( ##### )

Importing Contacts isn't an issue.  We're running Civi v5.39.0.

I'm matching by Contact ID and they all match, yet 100% of the rows imported return this error with the Contact ID in place of the #####.

Comment: have you checked there is no white space on the cid data you are importing? not sure why else you would get 'no match' if your data has eg a '51' and you have a contact with ID '51'

Comment: nope, there's no spaces after the ID numbers and I opened it in notepad to look for any funky ASCII codes for whitespaces

Comment: can you run a sample import on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and report back?

Comment: No issues importing to dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.  I also tried it on wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org and it went through.  I notice the Drupal demo site and WordPress demo are both running CiviCRM 5.44.alpha1 - is it possible there's an issue relateed to us running Civi v5.39.0 ?

Comment: asking you to test on master means 'we know the problem does not exist on latest'. next step (sorry) is to test on 'demo' eg http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1, but tbh my suspicion at this point is that something is slightly misaligned in your configuration. hopefully i am wrong and an upgrade will get you sorted

Comment: I'm getting a timeout error on both http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/ and http://wp.demo.civicrm.org/ -- though the 'master' sites are both working.  Is this common?  I'll try again over the weekend

Comment: it refreshes every 24 hours. so maybe you hit that. or something else

Comment: still no luck with the demo sites.. will keep trying and get back

Comment: hmm. try https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: oh i see you already mentioned that. anyway should let you test as suggested. i will raise a concern re demo sites